# Convergent sequence of functions in $L^2$ but unbounded derivatives?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have difficulties with this question.
Given $u_n \in C_c^{\infty}$, be a sequence converging to $u$ in $L^2\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$. Can we deduce that the sequence $\left(\nabla u_n\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is bounded?
I'm thinking about Taylor expansion, but I'm not sure it's right. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \in C_c(\mathbb R)$ with $f'(0)>0$ and $f_n(x)=f(nx)$. Then $f_n \to 0$ in $L^{2}$ (since $\int |f_n(x)|^{2}dx=\int |f(nx)|^{2}dx=\frac 1 n\int|f(y)|^{2}dx \to 0$ but $f_n'(0)=nf'(0) \to \infty$.